# While installing Rhytmbox, I get the following error

Tags: 12.04

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Isn't Rhythmbox installed by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox
```